# Login loop with Sharepoint/Office 365

Tags: firefox, office365, cookies, sharepoint

Recently I have disabled the option to allow third party cookies in Firefox. Immediately, I noticed that when I log in to Sharepoint/Office 365, the login seems successful, and redirects me to the home page as normal, but it seems to initiate a refresh of the page when the content has loaded.

Enabling third party cookies again fixes the problem. However, as I don't want third party cookies enabled on all sites, I have tried adding some cookies to the exceptions list, by first clearing all cookies from my browser, then finding whatever tries to get set from the login process. Despite adding what I saw, the problem still persists. There must be a cookie that I am missing, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Look what cookies are added when you login to Sharepoint/Office 365?

Comment: I assumed I got them all, as per the list above. This was done by going to Show Cookies in the privacy settings. Is there a way to see what cookies have been blocked?

Comment: " Is there a way to see what cookies have been blocked?" Not as far as I know ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure this one out. For some reason, Firefox was not listing all the set cookies when I checked using the method outlined in my question. I installed Chromium, where I could check the list of blocked cookies after disabling third party cookies, then added what I saw from that list, to the exceptions list in Firefox. Problem seems to be solved now.

I should be able to just run a process of elimination from the list to find the culprit, then block any other third party cookie that does not cause the loop issue.